# Java Function interface with bounded wildcard

Tags: java, functional-interface, bounded-wildcard, unbounded-wildcard

I'm trying to use `java.util.Function` object as an input to a library class.

```java
Function<? extends MyEntity, List> mapper;

public MyLibraryClass(Function<? extends MyEntity,List> mapper) {
    ...
}

public void aMethod(ClassExtendsMyEntity e) {
    mapper.apply(e);
}
```

The line `mapper.apply(e)` doesn't compile.
If I change to use `? super` instead of `? extends`, then the fail will be in the client using this library in the following code:

```java
Function<ClassExtendsMyEntity, List> mapper = e -> e.getListObjects();
new MyLibraryClass(mapper);
```

Can anyone help explain why getting this issue and if there is a way to get this working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: Remember PECS: _Producer Extends, Consumer Super_. Don't use `extends` for a consumer.

Comment: Well, you cannot write to nor read from a collection with a wildcard generic type (`?`). That is because `?` means *"an unknown, but specific type`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Function<? extends MyEntity,List> mapper;
```

This does *not* say "any subclass of `MyEntity` can be passed to `mapper`". It says "there exists some subclass of `MyEntity` that can be passed to `mapper`". It might be `ClassExtendsMyEntity`, it might be `MyEntity` itself, or it might be some crazy class that you've never even heard of.

`Function<T, S>` provides one function: `S apply(T arg)`. Since your argument type is `? extends MyEntity`, the *only* valid argument you can pass to `mapper.apply` is a value which is of *every* subtype of `MyEntity` at once, and there is no value that satisfies that condition.

Put more technically, the first argument of `Function<T, S>` is, in principle, contravariant, so using the covariant `? extends T` annotation makes little sense on it.

Depending on what you want, there are two solutions. If your function works for any `MyEntity`, then you should simply write `Function<MyEntity, List>` and forgo the generics/wildcards altogether. On the other hand, if you want `MyLibraryClass` to support only one subtype, but a subtype that you know about, then you need to make that a generic argument to `MyLibraryClass`.

```
public class MyLibraryClass<T extends MyEntity> {
  Function<? super T, List> mapper;

  public MyLibraryClass(Function<? super T, List> mapper) {
    ...
  }

  public void aMethod(T e) {
    mapper.apply(e);
  }

}
```

Again, the first type argument of `Function` is, in principle, contravariant, so we should use `? super T` to bound it by our type argument `T`. That means that if I have a `MyLibraryClass<ClassExtendsMyEntity>`, the function inside that might be a `Function<ClassExtendsMyEntity, List>`, or a `Function<MyEntity, List>`, or a `Function<Object, List>`, since all of those support `ClassExtendsMyEntity` arguments. For more on the reasoning behind that, see [What is PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Answer (score 2):

The declaration `Function<? extends MyEntity,List> mapper` means:
`mapper` expects an argument of some type `X` which is a subtype of `MyEntity`. The problem is, it doesn't tell what type it is.
And therefore the compiler can't verify if your call passing an instance of type `ClassExtendsMyEntity` is valid. After all `X` might be `SomeOtherClassExtendingMyEntity`.

In order to fix this just make the function type `Function<MyEntity,List>`